# Powershell and COM port connection

Tags: powershell, serial-port, usb

I'm using a simple powershell script (on Win10) to change the state of an usb controlled relay. It's job is (after sys startup) to open the com port (FTDI driver) send an ASCII command and that's it. Problem is, since the connection is not sustained on the COM port , every time I'm connecting a new usb device the relay is resetting to its original state. 
I was thinking about keeping the connection open by sending the command multiple times over time or checking the port status but first of all I need to be able to send a different command on system exit and second - it doesn't seem that elegant.

I'm sure there's an easy way around it - I simply don't have the knowledge to find it.

Thanks for the help !

The code is :

```
$port= new-Object System.IO.Ports.SerialPort COM6,9600,None,8,one
$port.open()

$port.WriteLine("d")
```